# What is this myth: elderly couple unwittingly feed gods, changed into tree

Tags: roman, greek, myth-identification

I studied Latin in 7th grade, and my teacher used to read some stories from Greek and Roman mythology to us. There is one of those that I wanted to learn more about, but haven't been able to find. Here is what I remember. Bear with me, that was over twenty years ago.

One god (or two?) is travelling disguised as a mortal. He asks an elderly, poor couple for hospitality, and is very well received. The couple goes as far as killing its only goose to feed the traveller.

If I remember correctly, they keep serving wine to the traveller, and realise something is weird because the amphora remains full.

Eventually the traveller reveals that he is a god and, to thank them for their generosity, turns them both into a tree, half oak and half olive tree or something of the sort, so that they will remain forever together.

As I said, it was a very long time ago, and I may have some elements wrong, but I think I remember the general idea correctly. Does someone know what Greek and/or Roman myth this is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### This is the myth of Baucis and Philemon.

Here is the Wikipedia page: [Baucis and Philemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baucis_and_Philemon), and here is one website with the full text (I think): [Tales Beyond Belief: Baucis and Philemon](http://www.talesbeyondbelief.com/myth-stories/baucis-and-philemon.htm).

By the way, the two gods were **Zeus** and **Hermes**, and the two trees were **oak** and **linden**.

Comment: And for good measure [here is one of the most famous version of the myth in Ovid's Metamorphoses](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/26073/26073-h/Met_VIII-XI.html#bookVIII_fableVI).